Recognizing commas separated rows as duplicates
I have this dataset that looks like this in R:
sample_table = data.frame( colors = c("red", "blue", "red,blue", "blue, red"), counts = c(12, 10, 5,6))

     colors counts
1       red     12
2      blue     10
3  red,blue      5
4 blue, red      6

I want to recognize that "blue, red" and "red, blue" is the same - and sum both counts into a single row:
    colors counts
1      red     12
2     blue     10
3 red,blue     11

Is there a standard way to do this in R (e.g. for multiple colors, e.g. "red, blue, green" = "green, blue, red")
I did this manually:
standardize_colors <- function(color_string) {
    colors <- unlist(strsplit(color_string, ",\\s*"))
    return(paste(sort(colors), collapse = ","))
}

sample_table$standardized_colors <- sapply(sample_table$colors, standardize_colors)

aggregated_table <- aggregate(counts ~ standardized_colors, data = sample_table, sum)

print(aggregated_table)

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

In base R, you could do the basic strsplit-rbind-approach like
 sample_table = data.frame( 
   colors = c("red", "blue", "red,blue", "blue, red"), counts = c(12, 10, 5,6))
 o = do.call("rbind", 
             lapply(l<-strsplit(sample_table$colors, ","), `length<-`, max(lengths(l))))
 sample_table = 
   cbind.data.frame(o, sample_table$counts) |> 
   setNames(c(paste0("col", seq(ncol(o))), "counts"))

and then adapt this beautfiul idea from user Onyambu
according to your needs like
 f = \(X) { 
   # if(nrow(X)==1L) X else 
   rbind(X[1L:2L,], f(X[!tapply(unlist(X[-3L]) %in% X[1L,], row(X[-3L]), sum), ])) 
 }
 f(sample_table)
#>   col1 col2 counts
#> 1  red <NA>     12
#> 2 blue <NA>     10
#> 4 blue  red      6


Edit:
Slight modifactions to your approach:
sample_table = data.frame( 
  colors = c("red", "blue", "red,blue", "blue, red"), counts = c(12, 10, 5,6))
sample_table$colors = vapply(sample_table$colors, 
                             \(x) strsplit((x), ",\\s*") 
                             |> unlist() |> sort() |> toString() , character(1L))
aggregate(counts ~ colors, data = sample_table, sum)

Where do you expect your bottle neck?

One approach with {dplyr}:
library(dplyr)

sample_table |> 
  mutate(colors = gsub('\\s*', '', colors) |>
           strsplit(',') |> 
           lapply(sort)
           ) |>
  summarise(counts = sum(counts), .by = colors)

Note that your variant with base R, while less concise, is clearly more efficient concerning speed (roughly twice as fast).

thanks! Is this the old format?

sample_table %>%
mutate(colors = gsub('\s*', '', colors) %>%
strsplit(',') %>%
lapply(sort)
) %>%
summarise(counts = sum(counts), .by = colors)

|> is the pipe operator of base R. It was introduced after the "tidyverse"'s pipe operator %>%. You can sure use either.

This base R solution is only slightly different than that in the question
but it is a bit shorter and is all in one pipeline.  It eliminates standarize_colors and unlist and replaces paste with the shorter toString.
sample_table |>
  transform(colors = sapply(strsplit(colors, ",\\s*"), \(x) toString(sort(x)))) |>
  aggregate(counts ~ colors, data = _, sum)

giving
     colors counts
1      blue     10
2 blue, red     11
3       red     12

